# ElasticSearch connection to Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2.4, reindex, elasticsearch, magento2.4.2

I'm new to Magento2.4 and Elasticsearch. I'm having an issue in connecting them in server setup. This works fine in my local(Windows) setup. When I try to setup in the server, it is not working as intended.

- OS - CentOS 8
- Apache - 2.4
- MariaDB - 15.1
- PHP - 7.4
- JAVA - 16.0
- Elasticsearch - 7.9.3

While re-indexing the site, it works fine and all the details are saved in Elasticsearch. When I run curl, I'm able to get the details from it. But, while testing the connection from Magento Admin panel, it fails. Also, the category page is broken. it shows the error `"Exception #0 (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException): No alive nodes found in your cluster"`.

Edit 1 - I've updated the to config restarted elasticsearch, run the commands

```
magento setup:upgrade
magento setup:di:compile
magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
magento cache:flush
```

Still the issue persists.
[image]

Thanks in advance for helping me fix the issue. :)

Comment: are you using the load balancer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your elastic search host name alternatively by typing

```
localhost:9200
```

Once you get the results as shown in the screen shot, you can copy the host name from there which is highlighted in the attached screen shot. I faced the similar problem and fixed by changing the host name.

[image: host name]

Answer (score 0):

Goto stores->configuration->catalog->catalog Search than select search engine as elastic search

- Elasticsearch Server Hostname:    localhost
- Elasticsearch Server Port:    9200
- Elasticsearch Index Prefix:   magento2
- Enable Elasticsearch HTTP Auth:   No
- Elasticsearch Server: Timeout

than restart elasticsearch server and click on test connection  if shows success message than it works fine

good luck

Comment: I've done that as well. But it's still the same.

Comment: @JayendharP if you are still in trouble than try this and check it carefully will help you: https://bobcares.com/blog/elasticsearch-no-alive-nodes-found-in-cluster/

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Elasticsearch with Apache Server Link are given below

Configure Elastic search with apache or nginx https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/es-config-apache.html

Answer (score 0):

please execute the below commands from your Magento root terminal

```
php bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine elasticsearch7
php bin/magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname localhost
php bin/magento config:set catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_port 9200
```

now for testing

```
curl -i https://example.com:8080/_cluster/heath
```

Here 8080 is the port in which your site is running.